# Openshift - What is the oc command to set environment From

Tags: openshift, redhat

In the Openshift Web Console, from the Deployment config, there is a "Environment From" section in the Environment tab.  The "Environment From" lets you add all key-value pairs from a config map or secret as environment variables.

Would anybody know what the oc command is to accomplish this using the oc CLI (Command Line Interface)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Import Environment from secret called mysecret to the Deployment Config called myapp

```
oc set env --from=secret/mysecret dc/myapp
```

Import Environment from configmap called myconfigmap and add "MYSQL_" prefix to the all environment variables to the Deployment Config called myapp

```
oc set env --from=configmap/myconfigmap --prefix=MYSQL_ dc/myapp

//or simple import without prefix

oc set env --from=configmap/myconfigmap dc/myapp
```

Comment: Is there any way I can specify the name of env variable? 
E.g. ```oc set env --from=secret/jkspassword --prefix=jks dc/myapp```
This creates environment variable ```jksPASSWORD```.
What if I just want to name it as ```jkspassword``` instead of default ```jksPASSWORD```.
Is it possible?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are lookin for:

oc env

Some examples in:

[https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#:~:text=OpenShift%20provides%20the%20oc%20env,that%20has%20a%20pod%20template](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#:%7E:text=OpenShift%20provides%20the%20oc%20env,that%20has%20a%20pod%20template).

EDIT:
I realized as mentioned in the comment below, that i did not read the question properly.

When you create your pod, you can reference a yaml file with the definition of the pod, and use of secret data: $ oc create -f mysecrets.yaml

The following link gives useful examples on how to both create a secret, and use it in the definition of a pod:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-examples

"Using Secrets" section shows how to create a secret. Example 3 shows how to use the secret when creating a pop to set environment variables

Hope this helps

Comment: I apologize, i realize i did not read the question properly. When you create your pod, you can reference a yaml file with the definition of the pod, and use of secret data:
$ oc create -f mysecrets.yaml
The following link gives useful examples on how to both create a secret, and use it in the definition of a pod:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-examples

"Using Secrets" section shows how to create a secret. Example 3 shows how to use the secret when creating a pod.

Hope this helps